# Progress of model.predict in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm playing with some tensorflow pre-trained models.

Given the following Tensorflow program:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--image_dir', default='img', type=str, help='Directory where images are kept.')
parser.add_argument('--output_dir', default='out', type=str, help='Directory where to output high res images.')


def main():
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Get all image paths
    image_paths = [os.path.join(args.image_dir, x) for x in os.listdir(args.image_dir)]

    # Change model input shape to accept all size inputs
    model = keras.models.load_model('models/generator.h5')
    inputs = keras.Input((None, None, 3))
    output = model(inputs)
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs, output)

    # Loop over all images
    for image_path in image_paths:

        # Read image
        low_res = cv2.imread(image_path, 1)

        # Convert to RGB (opencv uses BGR as default)
        low_res = cv2.cvtColor(low_res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # Rescale to 0-1.
        low_res = low_res / 255.0

        # Get super resolution image
        sr = model.predict(np.expand_dims(low_res, axis=0))[0]

        # Rescale values in range 0-255
        sr = ((sr + 1) / 2.) * 255

        # Convert back to BGR for opencv
        sr = cv2.cvtColor(sr, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        # Save the results:
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(args.output_dir, os.path.basename(image_path)), sr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Im trying to figure out how can I get the progress of the model.predict function

Any idea? I've been trying with verbose=1 but nothing happens

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need progress of `model.predict` specifically or the whole loop? The latter typically makes more sense.

Comment: Just the model.predict is fine

Comment: You can use `tqdm` package to get progress bar for the whole loop: `for image_path in tqdm(image_paths):`. I doubt if any progress over single graph call is possible

Comment: You can't, at least not on the API. It's typically not a long-running operation. In your case it looks like it should be very fast. In theory you could monitor what it reports in verbose mode or look at log stream from GPU / TPU.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [keras callbacks API](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/)

Below is example of [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) progress for prefiction, I used [keras-tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/keras-tqdm/) as inspiration (but they don't have a callback for *predict* operation so far)

#### tqdm_predict_callback.py

```py
class TQDMPredictCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, custom_tqdm_instance=None, tqdm_cls=tqdm, **tqdm_params):
        super().__init__()
        self.tqdm_cls = tqdm_cls
        self.tqdm_progress = None
        self.prev_predict_batch = None
        self.custom_tqdm_instance = custom_tqdm_instance
        self.tqdm_params = tqdm_params

    def on_predict_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
        pass

    def on_predict_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        self.tqdm_progress.update(batch - self.prev_predict_batch)
        self.prev_predict_batch = batch

    def on_predict_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.prev_predict_batch = 0
        if self.custom_tqdm_instance:
            self.tqdm_progress = self.custom_tqdm_instance
            return

        total = self.params.get('steps')
        if total:
            total -= 1

        self.tqdm_progress = self.tqdm_cls(total=total, **self.tqdm_params)

    def on_predict_end(self, logs=None):
        if self.tqdm_progress and not self.custom_tqdm_instance:
            self.tqdm_progress.close()
```

#### Usage

##### Single *predict* call

Below is a modified *predict* line from your code:

```py
from tqdm_predict_callback import TQDMPredictCallback 
#...
# Get super resolution image
sr = model.predict(
    np.expand_dims(low_res, axis=0),
    callbacks=[TQDMPredictCallback()]
)[0]
# ...
```

##### Multiple *predict* calls

```py
from tqdm_predict_callback import TQDMPredictCallback 
#...


# FIXME: you have to calculate amount of total batches manually, so
#   it should be:
#       total = batches_per_image * len(image_paths)
#   ...but perhaps you'll manage to update my code to avoid this.
total = None

with tqdm(total=total, desc="Running NN") as tqdm_progress:
    for image_path in image_paths:
        # Read image
        low_res = cv2.imread(image_path, 1)

        # ... (do some preparations)

        sr = model.predict(
            np.expand_dims(low_res, axis=0),
            callbacks=[TQDMPredictCallback(
                custom_tqdm_instance=tqdm_progress
            )]
        )[0]
# ...
```